# Como manter um item de uma ListView selecionada ao ser pressionada

Tags: java, android, listview

Estou desenvolvendo uma listView, e preciso deixar um item selecionado quando clicar, e depois pegar a posição daquele item, para poder fazer a inversão de dois itens, o que ta em cima com o que ta em baixo por exemplo, por meio de um botão. Andei pesquisando mas as soluções que achei exigiam uma API maior que a 11, e estou fazendo na API 8, porque meu programa é bem simples. Como faço para manter selecionada e retornar a posição do item que esta selecionado? Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro crie uma classe derivada de `LinearLayout` ou `RelativeLayout` que implemente a interface `Checkable`

**Exemplo para `LinearLayout`**

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable{

    private boolean checked = false;
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

      // Requer API level 11
/*    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                   int defStyle) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      }*/

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
         final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
         if (isChecked())
             mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
         return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked(){
        return checked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!checked);
    }
}
```

Você deve então usar este Layout para definir o Layout dos itens da sua lista:

**lista_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<yourPackage.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listItemLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</yourPackage.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Nos dados associados à lista você tem de ter uma flag `boolean` que indicará se está selecionado ou não.

No `Adapter` verifique a flag e faça `listItemLayout.setChecked(false)` ou `listItemLayout.setChecked(true);` conforme a flag.

No onClick associado à lista deve colocar a flag com `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar layouts customizados para gerar esse efeito de pressed ou normal.
No item da lista pode ter uma flag boolean enable e quando pressionar o item, você setEnable(true) e listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Dá um olhada nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868194/android-xml-layout-for-a-listview-with-different-items

Comment: Você poderia trazer a parte mais relevante para termos conteúdo em português também?